# Identity nearby devices using XAMARIN with BLE

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using XAMARIN CrossBluetoothLE to scan for devices and phones nearby. I have a working prototype but the scan does not pick up tablets and phones even when I have their bluetooth settings open so that they are visible. Is there another level to identify phones that a regular BLE scan does not include.

Also, any suggestions on another approach to scan for devices other than BLE? I don't need any details I just need to know the number of devices in range.

Below is the XAMARIN Code:

```
    private async void BLE()
    {
        var ble = CrossBluetoothLE.Current;
        var adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
        var state = ble.State;

        adapter.ScanMode = Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts.ScanMode.LowLatency;

        adapter.ScanTimeout = 10000;

        ble.StateChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            Log.Info(TAG, "The bluetooth state changed to {e.NewState}");
        };

        adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
        {
            if (a.Device.Name != null)
                Log.Info(TAG, "Discovered: " + a.Device.Name.ToString());
        };

        adapter.DeviceAdvertised += (s, a) =>
        {
            if (a.Device.Id != null)
                Log.Info(TAG, "Device advertised: " + a.Device.Id.ToString());
        };

        await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you share your code with us to have a look

Comment: have you set up the permissions accordingly if your targetSdk is 23+ or other ?The location services must be on,and request runtime permission

Comment: @FreakyAli, I edited my post to include the code.

Comment: @ Leo Zhu - MSFT, Yes I have the permissions in the manifest and enabled them in the app. I am able to discover non phone and non tablets nearby.

Comment: Are you sure that it is functionality that is possible with Xamarin Native? Could you please give an example of an app's functionality you are trying to mimic?

Comment: I leveraged my code off of this: https://github.com/didourebai/BLEPluginDemo